# Windows 10 suddenly keeps disabling all network adapters

Tags: windows-10, networking

**Windows 10 suddenly disables all network adapters** (LAN and USB-WI-FI). Upon re-enabling they get disabled again the moment they try to connect to the router.

**A Linux-Live system on the same machine can connect to the internet normally.** I think that excludes hardware issues. The LAN and WI-FI networks work fine with other devices, including a Win 10 PC, which rules out network problems.

It has to be the Win 10 installation. I tried a few things like re-installing the drivers, resetting the network, deep malware scan, switching off Windows Defender but without success.

Finally, I simple chose a restore point and voila, Windows would enable the adapters and allow internet access like before. The joy did not last long. After a few hours the issue re-appeared. Same "solution". And again ...

**Any idea what might cause this issue**? Otherwise: **should I simply give up** and install a fresh version of Windows or should I try to update the old one (if the restored system's connection lasts long enough)?

System: desktop PC with Windows 10 1903, CPU 2x2.9 GHz, 8 GB DDR3 RAM. Wi-Fi is USB, LAN is on-board.

Update: In the meantime, I updated to 1909. So far, it holds. I'll update the post should the issue return.

Comment: It is likely the drivers. Seen it before. You need to uninstall the hardware using device manager and also delete the drivers. Before doing anything else, reboot. If that doesn't fix it, download the drivers from the website first (use another pc and usb stick if you have to) and delete the devices + delete drivers again, this time without reboot, install the drivers from the website so other drivers get installed, then reboot. If the latter works, windows update may install the wrong drivers again.

Comment: @LPChip: The network adapters are based on standard RT chips and if there were an issue with the drivers Windows provided, millions if not billions of people would have the same problem. Automatic updates is switched off, so there was no change from that side which makes it unlikely the the driver issue is related to the adapters. However, I already mentioned that I re-installed the drivers.

Comment: **Update 2**: The issue did not return after the Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

> I chose a restore point and voila, Windows would enable the adapters
> and allow internet access like before. The joy did not last long.
> After a few hours the issue re-appeared. Same "solution". And again
> ...

This indicates the need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install or a new Windows User Account.

**First:** make a new, test Windows User Account (Settings, Accounts). Log into the new Account and test network settings.

If a new user account fixes the issue, you need to back up the documents and email in your user Account, make a new User Account (make sure it is a member of Administrators if this is your own machine).

**Second:** if the issue is not related to the User Account, do the Windows 10 Repair Install.  Note the 3 possible methods below (for increasingly difficult problems).

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

A fresh install may have to follow after the above suggestions, but I have been successful over 90% of the time doing a Repair before a fresh install.

Comment: This is a bit over the top... Its more likely that windows update updates the drivers and causes havoc. This is more of a last-resort solution. I'm positive the problem here is faulty drivers. Either the chipset, usb layer or network cards themselves. Usually when people reinstall drivers, they just delete the device in device manager and let windows install the device again with the same drivers. This fixes most problems but not all. I think that is what's happening here.

Comment: It could be drivers but since repeated “go back to a prior restore point” fixes and then breaks again is just as likely operating system. Also the Repair will likely update needed drivers. 

We need the OP to post.

Comment: To rule out hardware failure of the mainboard it is perhaps a good idea to let Linux run for a week or so.  before I repair Windows into the blue. I think I would prefer a clean install instead of repair anyway.

Comment: A Repair is better than a clean install in most cases because data will be kept. It is definitely worth a try before fresh install. Most problems will get fixed this way.